# Как получить List из Flowable RxJava

Tags: rxjava

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить List из Flowable? Есть метод, который возвращает List. Внутри него идёт запрос к бд, через метод, который возвращает Flowable>. Как конвертировать его в массив строк?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужны методы `Flowable.fromIterable()` и `Flowable.toList()`.

Пример использования:

```
final Flowable<List<String>> foo = Flowable.fromIterable(list)
        .flatMap { getFromDb(it) }
        .toList()
        .toFlowable()
```

где `getFromDb(it)` метод запроса к БД, который возвращает `Flowable<String>`